# Get all items from a folder using REST

Tags: rest, list-item, getlist

Currently I am using REST in order to get item titles in the Pages directory. The problem is that it is pulling all the elements that are in the pages directory and I only want it to pull from a certain subfolder in the pages directory.

```
var moduleServiceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules";
```

This is what the call currently looks like.

Answer (score 11):

Try to use this endpoint `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` to return all files and folder at a specific folder URL

```
https://server/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Folders,Files
```

**To return only all files at a specific folder URL**

```
https://server/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Files
```

For more details check [get all the files and folders contained inside a SharePoint folder in one rest API call.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call)

Also if you need work with CSOM check [How to get all the files inside the folder in list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115980/how-to-get-all-the-files-inside-the-folder-in-list)

Comment: It only retrieves the first 100 and includes a link to "next 100" Is there any way to pull everything in the list without pagination?

Comment: Add to your url the parameter: &$top=1000

Answer (score 1):

The query you are using will return all items irrespective of type (folder/file). You can use change to below syntax.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<<folder relative path>>')/Files
```

Example for folder relative path is

```
/[subsite]/<<library name>>/<<folder name>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('{listTitle}')/Items?$filter=FileDirRef eq '{serverRelativeUrl}'
```

However it will only give items from the specific folder.

This query:

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('{listTitle}')/Items?$filter=startswith(FileDirRef, '{serverRelativeUrl}')
```

should return items from other sub folders also.

Comment: Thanks, that filter is what I needed to restrict results to a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you need but in order to get attributes of a subfolder you need to access the folder first through this endpoint GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderProperties) is a Microsoft documentation regarding Files and folders REST API call.

Answer (score -1):

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Lists/getbyTitle('" + LibraryName + "')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Id&$top=5000
```

This URL will Resolve ur all problems