# Get specific page (file) from folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using REST to get item page by specific title,

My question is how to get the specific page in folder from list Pages

Here is my code snippet :

```
var folder;  //folder
var source;                                         
var page_title = "myPage";
$.ajax({
        url: "https://app.gro.net/sites/ight/fr-fr/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + page_title +"'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.d.results[0]) {
                //var source = $('#content')[0];
                       source = data.d.results[0].Desc;
            }

        },
       error: function(){ //Error }
   }});
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Share the error message that you are getting..

Comment: @ Rohit Waghela, There is no error since url is not the right then it ignores the ajax call . thank you for quick response

Comment: I found this publication  interesting but I didn't quite understand how to do it   :     https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194534/get-all-items-from-a-folder-using-rest

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by publication ??  And is your issue resolved ??

Comment: @ Rohit Waghela With my script I only get pages that are not in a folder, now my page is in a folder

Comment: @ Faxel You can use `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` to get items from specific folder. Refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64287/discussion-between-rohit-waghela-and-faxelf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to retrieve a page in a specific folder with CAML & REST.

```
var dm = "PageName";
var queryText =  "" + dm + "";


function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText,folderUrl) 
{
    var viewXml = '' + queryText + '';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml,
                      "FolderServerRelativeUrl": folderUrl 
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}


getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Pages', '', 'Pages/Folder')
.then(function(data)
{
    
     var items = data.d.results[0].Title;
        
        console.log(items);  
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

PS: to resolve this issue "Value does not fall within the expected range error in Rest API" please refer :

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-error-in-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

**Pages** is not a list. its library. so you can get & filter file by below api,

```
 _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages')/Files?$filter=Title eq 'test'
```

Below is full code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getfiles();
    });


    function getfiles() {
        var pageTitle = 'test';
        var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
        $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages')/Files?$filter=Title eq '"+pageTitle+"'",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: requestHeaders,
            success: onSuccess,
            async: false,
            error: onError
        }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
            alert(data.d.results[0].Name);
        } function onError(error) {
            alert("Error on retrieving page.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tested with but I still have an empty result, my url is good?  : ** URL : "https://ap.gup.honet/sites/sight/fr-fr/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages')/Files?$filter=Title eq '" + page_title +"'",**

Comment: I have updated answer with full code. check it.

Comment: thank you for your help, But I still have the empty result [] "data.d.results" , For information the file I am looking for is in a folder X in the library Page   Like that  :  Pages(lib) --> Folder X --> MyPage(file)  ,   You think I should use JSOM like explains this post?  (https://info.paitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint-rest-api-and-lists-with-folders)

Comment: In API url, just change ('Pages') to ('Pages/Folder X') & try.

Comment: Thank you very much Vishal for your help, but I always have the result empty, I will try to do this with csom and after I post the answer, thank you Vishal.